# Multithreading in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I've built a lot of traditional web apps with Rails doing contract jobs, and now I'm working with a client who wants to add some live streaming features to his site using Rails 4 ActionController::Live. What he wants to do involves massive numbers of people listening to the same server sent events (I think). I'm very (very) new to multithreading / sse concepts, and I have two questions.

First, if I were to build a chat room (I'm not), and 10,000 people were all in the same chat, do I need 10,000 concurrent threads, or is there a more clever way to handle that situation?

Second, what are some good resources to learn about multithreading with Rails in depth?

Thanks

Comment: No, you don't need 10000 concurrent threads.

Comment: What would you do with all those threads?

Comment: @Dave - I have no idea. Like I mentioned, I'm completely new to the concept. In looking into the new Live module, it seems that if someone is listening to a particular event, it spawns a new thread for them. I'm sure that is completely wrong. Any idea where I can learn more about this?

Comment: Instead of saying that they don't need them, a better comment would be to get clarification or explain WHY he doesn't need them. https://github.com/heroku-examples/ruby-websockets-chat-demo/blob/master/middlewares/chat_backend.rb#L17 this example shows that if you're using redis for PubSub to handle notifications, you need to create new threads since it is a blocking operation. Its not Rails but its the same concept and it uses Websockets as opposed to EventSource.

Comment: Might be worth a read: https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/getting-started-with-ruby-and-websockets